# Super Keyword shows error in my java code

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

```
@ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public class MandatoryValidationException extends Exception{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    public MandatoryValidationException(String errorCode, String message){
        super(errorCode,message);
    }
}
```

When I try to use two arguments it shows an error and says "Remove argument to match exception". Some one please suggest me.

Comment: There is no constructor of `Exception` that accepts two Strings. Because your class `extends Exception` a `super` call to a constructor of the superclass must refer to an existing constructor of the Exception class: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html

Comment: How about looking for a constructor which takes 2 `String` arguments in the `Exception` class?

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to extend the Exception class and then calling the constructer of Exception class but the Exception class doesn't have any constructer with provided arguments
for more details check this out
[1]: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html